# remove subquery from view to make it Indexed view

Tags: sql-server, view

i want to create a Index View for full text search.

the only problem i,m facing with subquery, because index views does not allow subquery.

below is my query

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[Demo] with SCHEMABINDING  AS
select distinct a.ID,a.Title, a.Description ,b.Name as Recipe, c.Name as Taste , d.Name as CuisineType,
STUFF((SELECT ',' + Name FROM dbo.Ingredients where ID in (select IngredientID from dbo.listingIngredients 
where listingid = a.ID ) FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as Ingredients
from dbo.Listing as a 
inner join dbo.RecipeType b on a.RecipeTypeID = b.ID
inner join dbo.taste c on a.tasteID = c.ID
inner join dbo.CuisineType d on a.CuisineTypeID = d.ID
inner join dbo.listingIngredients e on a.ID = e.listingID
GO
```

I,m using subquery to get ingredients as  concatenate string from Ingredients table using STUFF.
[image]

can some one please let me know how can i remove this subquery and have ingredients as contented string.

please let me know

regards
manish

Comment: There are a number of [restrictions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432(v=sql.105).aspx) that must be met in order for a view to be indexable. My rule of thumb is - if you've got a query that currently breaks one of the restrictions, any attempt to re-write it will encounter another of the restrictions. The restrictions aren't just arbitrarily decided - there's (generally) no decent way for the database engine to work out a way to maintain an index that breaks them.

Comment: I,m left with no alternative because for full text search we need to have indexed view..:(..please let me know if there are any other alternatives..apart from full text search..the only option i see is dynamic SQL...:(

Comment: The only obvious transformation is to eliminate the grouping behaviour entirely and have one row per ingredient. Once you've gone that far though, it's not clear why full-text indexing the original tables isn't sufficient.

Comment: if i dont have grouping behavior, then there will be duplicates, are you suggesting that duplicates are fine..and i should avoid them in a business logic layer??...

Comment: and i cant have single ingredient because a food listing will always multiple ingredients..there will be a main ingredient and rest all sub ingredients...

Answer (score 1):

The XML part of the query will cause problems, even if you did manage to remove the sub-selected.

However, all is not lost. You could rewrite the view into a part that can be indexed and another part that is cheaper, but can't. For example, you could write:

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[Demo_Part] with SCHEMABINDING  AS
select a.ID,a.Title
, a.Description 
, b.Name as Recipe
, c.Name as Taste 
, d.Name as CuisineType
, e.name
from dbo.Listing as a 
inner join dbo.RecipeType b on a.RecipeTypeID = b.ID
inner join dbo.taste c on a.tasteID = c.ID
inner join dbo.CuisineType d on a.CuisineTypeID = d.ID
inner join dbo.listingIngredients e on a.ID = e.listingID
GROUP BY a.ID,a.Title
, a.Description 
, b.Name as Recipe
, c.Name as Taste 
, d.Name as CuisineType
, e.name
```

Depending on your data model, you may not even need the group by. This view can be indexed

And then write another view that is not indexed, but which replaces your original view

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Demo]
SELECT ...
 STUFF (...)
FROM [dbo].[Demo_Part]
```

As a meta-answer I would add that if you need to index a view like this (and use the DISTINCT), chances are that your data modeller made a pretty big mistake with the data model or that your data access code is very inefficient. Everything about this smells like you are trying to work around poor coding and modelling practices.