# SQL converting rows to string using Inner Join only

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, inner-join

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [remove subquery from view to make it Indexed view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14434865/remove-subquery-from-view-to-make-it-indexed-view)

I have three tables

1) Listings

```
ID          Title                                                                                                                                                                                                    
----------------------
27          KFC Chiken                                                                                                                                                                                               
28          Manish Wowly                                                                                                                                                                                             
29          BB                                                                                                                                                                                                       
30          Woderla                                                                                                                                                                                                  
31          funny                                                                                                                                                                                                    
32          Demo123                                                                                                                                                                                                  
33          final                                                                                                                                                                                                    
34          Demo Works                                                                                                                                                                                               
35          real                                                                                                                                                                                                     
36          listing123
```

2) Ingredients

```
ID          Name                                                                                                                                                                                                     
----------------------
33          Chiken                                                                                                                                                                                                   
34          Rice
```

3) Listing Ingredients

```
ID          IngredientId ListingId   IsMainIngredient
----------- ------------ ----------- ----------------
3           33           33          1
4           33           34          1
5           33           35          1
6           33           36          1
7           33           37          1
8           34           33          1
9           33           27          1
10          34           27          1
```

and i,m looking for output similar to without using subquery and only using Inner join because i want to create a indexed view out of this query

```
  ID          title                   Ingredients                                                                                                                                                                                 
----------- ---------------------------------------
27          KFC Chiken              Chiken,Rice                                                                                                                                                                                 
33          final                   Chiken,Rice                                                                                                                                                                                 
34          Demo Works              Chiken                                                                                                                                                                                 
35          real                    Chiken                                                                                                                                                                                 
36          listing123              Chiken                                                                                                                                                                                 
37          Working Chiken          Chiken
```

Comment: Sql server 2008.. i know..but for indexed view we can not use subquery or join expect inner join

Comment: because i want to use it for full text query

Comment: What kind of full text query do you need to run? If you are looking for `title` that contains a set of `ingredients` you don't need a full text query.